# How to store and retrieve data to Firestore with the user unique id?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

[image: USER FIRESTORE]
[image: TRANSACTIONEXPENSE firestore]

I'm trying to make a money manager application and it has a user login. When the user login to the application, they will show their own transaction. But my problem is when the user login, the user can see all the data (not only their data) which means that the transaction is not add to unique id and not display based on the unique id that login to the system. Anyone can help me to fix this? I can't find any resource about this one. Please Help me. Thank you

RECORD FORM

```
import 'package:dropdownfield/dropdownfield.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/transaction_daily.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/record_code.dart';

class RecordExpense extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecordExpenseState createState() => _RecordExpenseState();
}

class _RecordExpenseState extends State<RecordExpense> {
  //DatabaseReference _ref;
  final date = TextEditingController();
  final category = TextEditingController();
  final amount = TextEditingController();
  final description = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email, _password;

  Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
    Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
    //return uid;
  }

  @override
  String selectExpense;

  final expenseSelected = TextEditingController();



  List <String> expensecategories = [
    "Food",
    "Social Life",
    "Transportation",
    "Beauty",
    "Household",
    "Education",
    "Health",
    "Gift",
    "Other"
  ];


  DateTime _selectedDate;

  void initState(){
    //_ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Transaction');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference collect= firestore.collection("TransactionExpense");

    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User user =_auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;


    String dates;
    String amounts;
    String selectExpenses;
    String descriptions;
    return new Form(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

          child: Column(
            key: _formKey,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                  controller: date,
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectDate(context);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Date",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                    hintText: "Select Date",
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                  controller: amount,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Amount",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                    hintText: "Amount",
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: secondary),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: DropDownField(
                    controller: expenseSelected,
                    hintText: "Select Category",
                    labelText: "Category",
                    enabled: true,
                    itemsVisibleInDropdown: 4,
                    items: expensecategories,
                    onValueChanged: (dynamic value) {
                      selectExpense = value;
                    },
                    value: selectExpense,
                    required: false,
                  ),
                ),
              ),


              Container(
                //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20,0),
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                  controller: description,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Descriptions",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                    hintText: "Expense Description",
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 25.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(

                          onPressed: () async {
                            /*
                                UserCredential _user =
                                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
                                String _uid = _user.user.uid;

                                 */

                            //await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('TransactionExpense').doc(_uid).set({
                            /*
                                collect.add({
                                  'date': date.text,
                                  'amount': 'RM' + amount.text,
                                  'category': selectExpense,
                                  'description': description.text,
                              });
                              date.text = "";
                              amount.text = "";
                              description.text = "";

                                 */
                            final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth
                                .instance;
                            final User user = _auth.currentUser;
                            final uid = user.uid;

                            await DatabaseService().updateData(
                                uid, date.text, amount.text,
                                selectExpense, description.text);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                              "Save".toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          )),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(15)),
                            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all<Color>(Colors.white),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all<Color>(Colors.pink),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                      15.0),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: secondary)
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20, height: 10),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            clearButton();
                          },
                          child: Text(
                              "Clear".toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14
                          )),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(15)),
                            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all<Color>(Colors.white),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                .all<Color>(Colors.pink),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                      15.0),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: secondary)
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void clearButton(){
    date.clear();
    amount.clear();
    category.clear();
    description.clear();
  }
  _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime newSelectedDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: _selectedDate != null ? _selectedDate : DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2000),
        lastDate: DateTime(2040),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                primary: secondary,
                onPrimary: Colors.black,
                surface: primary,
                onSurface: Colors.white,
              ),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
            ),
            child: child,
          );
        });

    if (newSelectedDate != null) {
      _selectedDate = newSelectedDate;
      date
        ..text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate)
        ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
            offset: date.text.length,
            affinity: TextAffinity.upstream));
    }
  }
}
class AlwaysDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool get hasFocus => false;
}
```

LIST VIEW CODE

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference collect = firestore.collection("TransactionExpense");

    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User user = _auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;
    print('uid: $uid');

    String date = '';
    String amount = '';
    String selectExpense = '';
    String description = '';

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: collect.doc(uid).get(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
            date = data['date'];
            amount = data['amount'];
            selectExpense = data['selectExpense'];
            description = data['description'];
            return ListView(children: [
              Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          selectExpense,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 6,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          date,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amount,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            collect.doc(uid).delete();
                            //_showDeleteDialog();
                            //_showDeleteDialog(document: document);
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.delete_forever_outlined,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 6,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a unique user id from firebase auth with:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user =_auth.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;
```

Then, use that uid to create a unique document in your collection when the user signs up and to read using:

```
firestore.collection("TransactionExpense").doc(uid);
```

Create a new file, call it whatever you want. In that file:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  Future updateData(String uid, String date, String amount,
      String selectExpense, String description) async {
    CollectionReference collect =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("TransactionExpense");
    return await collect.doc(uid).set({
      'date': date,
      'amount': 'RM' + amount,
      'category': selectExpense,
      'description': description,
    });
  }
}
```

Now from the button that you want to update with:

```
import 'YOUR_FILE_NAME';

onPressed: () async {
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user =_auth.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;

await DatabaseService().updateData(uid, date.text, amount.text, selectExpense, description.text);

}
```

Now, in your firestore database, you should have a different document for each user.

To read data of individual users, use a `FutureBuilder` in your list view like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
...


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference collect = firestore.collection("TransactionExpense");

    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User user = _auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;
    print('uid: $uid');

    String date = '';
    String amount = '';
    String selectExpense = '';
    String description = '';

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: collect.doc(uid).get(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
            date = data['date'];
            amount = data['amount'];
            selectExpense = data['selectExpense'];
            description = data['description'];
            return ListView(children: [
              Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          selectExpense,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 6,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          date,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amount,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            collect.doc(uid).delete();
                            //_showDeleteDialog();
                            //_showDeleteDialog(document: document);
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.delete_forever_outlined,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 6,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: hi, where should i write code for the store data to Firestore?

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. where should I add this one? final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user =_auth.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;
firestore.collection("TransactionExpense").doc(uid); and in the buttom, the updateData shows red line : "instance member 'updateData' can't be accessed using static access'. How to fix?

Comment: hi, sorry about the error, fixed it with: await DatabaseService().updateData(uid, date.text, amount.text, selectExpense, description.text);
don't worry about final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; final User user =_auth.currentUser; final uid = user.uid; firestore.collection("TransactionExpense").doc(uid);, I've included that in your onPressed function.

Comment: yes it is stored to database, but it is not based on user id. If I login with other user, the data still appear. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't know you wanted to read the data as well. Added another code block for that, try it out and let me know if it works!

Comment: hi sorry, where should I input for the future builder? I want to make if the user login to application, it will store the document based on user ID @MIND BLOWER

Comment: In the login page you don't need a future builder, change what I previously told in the login page. Wherever you're supposed to display this data use a future builder on the top, after widget build, as shown. 
I am sorry if this still doesn't clarify it for you, please let me know where you're displaying the data and then we can work it out!

Comment: sorry I got error in the return Future Builder what should I do? because I'm new in flutter and firebase

Comment: maybe I can edit the current code that I have write? @MIND BLOWER

Comment: Yes, please! that would be helpful. Also, can you tell me what error you're getting?

Comment: I have edit the code, can you check? For the error I missed the bracket but now is ok. but still, when I login with other account, the record are stored to all the account

Comment: Hmmm, by any chance, could you show me how your firestore database looks like? Also try saving from one account and see how it updates on firestore.

Comment: I already add the Firestore picture, in the questions. please check

Comment: Oh thanks for the picutres, it seems to be working great. I am not sure if you're using these variables:  String dates;
    String amounts;
    String selectExpenses;
    String descriptions;  this is where the data is stored

Comment: so I need to delete the variable? because I want to make 1 user have different data to store

Comment: No no you don't need to delete the variable. I think I have understood your problem. The code that you've uploaded ("RECORD FORM"), is where you're asking the user to input data right? And this doesn't have anything that actually shows the data right? You should use the `Future Builder` where you want to display the user data in you app, not where you're inputting the data. If you are still stuck, it would be very helpful if you share the code for where you want to display the spefic user data.

Comment: No the data already display. but my problem is.. if I login with user1 account, and add the data (yes it is stored). but when I login with different user account (user2), the data from user1 also display in user2 list view. I want to separate their data which mean each of the user have their own transaction (not combine).

Comment: Yes I understand that. Can you show me the code for the list view?

Comment: yes, I already add the list view code. Can you check?

Comment: Yes! this is where you need to use the future builder, because the problem is, you are not using the uid here. So, remove the `FutureBuilder` from record form, and replace stream builder in your listview with a futurebuilder instead. Before you do that, can you tell me if you need to read the data from firestore only one time after the list view page is launched, or do you want the data on listview to live update depending on changes on firestore?

Comment: I updated the last code block with the full list view code, try it out! Let me know if there are any errors or changes that you need me to make

Comment: hi I got this error A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'. @MIND BLOWER

Comment: Made small edits in the code, can you try now?String date = '';
    String amount = '';
    String selectExpense = '';
    String description = '';

Comment: hi, I got this error The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("date")

Comment: Can you print the uid, where i've edited the code block from my answer. And then check if that uid docment has the values data in cloud firestore? Because this should work, it's from the official [FlutterFire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage)

Comment: also try logging out and logging in with a new account

Comment: I don't know why I always got error like this The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>#96de4):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("date")

Comment: Can you update the new code in your question so maybe i can see?

Comment: I also updated if(snapshot.hasData) to  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done), try that too maybe. And did you try logging out and logging in with a new account?

Comment: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null' I got this error and yes I already register new account and try to add record

Comment: and yes I have edit the code in the question

Comment: in your debug console you should see the uid, as I added the print('uid: $uid');. Can you tell me what that uid is from the debug console, and then check if that uid matches the uid in the database?

Comment: hey, may I know where is the uid?

Answer (score 0):

```
/// This is how you can sign in
UserCredential _userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'email', password: 'password');
String uid = _userCredential.user.uid; // this is UID of logged in user

/// Set data in document
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection').doc(uid).set({
  "key1": "Value1",
  "key2": "Value2",
});

/// Retrieve data from document
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection').doc(uid).get();

/// Update data in document
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection').doc(uid).update({
  "key2": "updatedValue",
});

/// Delete document
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection').doc(uid).delete();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. what should I write for the 'your unique id'? because I'm trying to  make when they login, they can store their own data (not mix with other data)

Comment: You will get `uid` when you logged in, this is your unique ID

Comment: Which method you used for login? And aren't you storing user data to firestore while sign up?

Comment: I'm using Firebase authentication but I also store it to firestore

Comment: yes, but all the unique id is different right? so what should I write if I want to get the user id that login to the system?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check and let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: I tried for the store data first, it shows error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] null

Comment: hi, where should I sent you the code snippet?

Comment: You can add edit your question and add specific code.

Comment: alright, I have update the code. can you check?

Comment: Are you able to get `uid` with the help of `final uid = user.uid;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234101/discussion-between-new-user-and-hemal).